# Concrete example using elliptic integral of the second kind to calculate arc length?

Tags: elliptic-integrals

There's an identical question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/364768/incomplete-elliptic-integral-of-the-second-kind-and-the-arc-length-of-an-ellipse) but it was never answered fully and the link providing an essential component of the accepted "answer" is broken. The Keisan website presents a solution [here (PDF)](https://keisan.casio.com/keisan/lib/real/system/2006/1343722259/Elliptic%20arc%20length.pdf) that shows the length of an arc going clockwise from the Y axis as $${s(x) = aE({x \over a},k)}$$

Consider an ellipse with a = 20, b = 5 (k = 0.9682) and an arc starting at (0,5) and ending at (7.3625, 4.6489). E(0.3681, 0.9682) = 0.3604, according to the [Keisan integral calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1244989948), yielding an arc length of 7.208. But using [Keisan's own arc length calculator](https://keisan.casio.com/exec/system/1343722259) (the angle is 32.27°) yields a length of 7.3736. Close, but not exact.

For an arc ending at (18.8774, 1.6516): E(0.9439, 0.9682) = 0.8196 yields a length of 16.392 versus the calculated 19.3729 (angle of 5°). Considerably off.

Keisan certainly seems to have done something right in their arc length calculator! But I can't duplicate their results, so I'm clearly missing something in the calculation of the parameters and/or the application of the formula. Can anyone provide a clue, or suggest a concrete path for how to apply arc parameters such as these to the elliptic integral to calculate the arc length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula should be
$$\color{blue}{s(x)=a E\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{a}\right)|1-\frac{b^2}{a^2}\right)}$$ So, for your case $(a=20,b=5,x=\frac{73625}{10000}=\frac{589}{80})$, the result is
$$20 E\left(\sin ^{-1}\left(\frac{589}{1600}\right)|\frac{15}{16}\right) \approx 7.37381$$
while $$20 E\left(\frac{589}{1600}|\frac{15}{16}\right) \approx 7.20786$$ So, a typo !

Comment: Both answers look correct, but bonus points here for including the clear formula! This works for me, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The mismatch comes from a confusion in the definition of the elliptic integral.

In the PDF :
$$E_{PDF}(X,k)=\int_0^X \sqrt{\frac{1-k^2t^2}{1-t^2}}dt$$
and for example, with $X=\frac{x}{a}\simeq\frac{7.3625}{20}=0.368125$
$$E_{PDF}(X,k)=E_{PDF}(0.368125 ,0.968246) =\int_0^X \sqrt{\frac{1-k^2t^2}{1-t^2}}dt\simeq 0.3687$$
$$s=aE_{PDF}(X,k)\simeq 20(0.3687)=7.3738$$
which is the correct approximate of the arc length.

The standard definition of the Incomplete Elliptic Integral definition is :
$$E_{}(\phi,k)=\int_0^{\phi} \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta=\int_0^{\sin(\phi)} \sqrt{\frac{1-k^2t^2}{1-t^2}}dt$$
where $t=\sin(\theta)$

With the above example $\phi=\sin^{-1}(X)\simeq \sin^{-1}(0.368125)=0.376992$
$$E(\phi,k)=E(0.376992,0.968246)= \int_0^{\phi} \sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2(\theta)}d\theta \simeq 0.3687$$
$$s=aE(\phi,k)\simeq 20(0.3687)=7.3738$$
This is the same result than above.

In a word, the mistake is in $E(0.368125 ,0.968246)\simeq 0.3601$ which should be $E(0.376992,0.968246)\simeq 0.3687$ .